# Getting Error while creating audience of CUSTOM type through Marketing API - Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook PHP SDK, and trying to create Audience of Custom TYPE from Marketing API, and I am getting following Error:

> You'll need to agree to the Custom Audience terms before you can
>   create or edit an audience of CUSTOM type. To accept, go to
>   https://business.facebook.com/ads/manage/customaudiences/tos/?act=129260934125705.

Even though I have already accepted the term, I am still getting the error for accepting the terms.

Please find attached screenshot for Terms Acceptance.. [Terms & Condition Accepted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvftt.png)

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the status of `tos_accepted` via [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). You can also use it to debug your Audience Creation calls.

You can check if a Business has signed their Custom Audience terms of service, by making a GET call to an ad account owned by that Business. The ad account can’t be acting on behalf of another business, or be shared. The GET call is:

```
GET act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>?fields=tos_accepted
```

A sample response looks like this:

```
{
  "tos_accepted": {
    "custom_audience_tos": 1 // this means the terms were signed
  },
  "id": "act_<AD_ACCOUNT>"
}
```

Check full docs about TOS [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/custom-audience-terms-of-service)

A bit more info on [Custom Audiences](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Artyom Kovalyov.. I have checked the graph API explorer, and this is what I get.

`{
  "tos_accepted": {
    "web_custom_audience_tos": 1,
    "custom_audience_tos": 1,
    "value_based_custom_audience_tos": 1
  },
  "id": "act_129260934125705"
}`

Please check and let me know if I can do something else to fix the error that I am getting..

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok Vishal. Have you tried to create this same Audience via graph explorer? The ways to go from here are either filing an FB direct support case for your app, they are not usually fast to reply and not every customer is whitelisted for that.

Another assumption is if you try to do it on behalf of your customer with their account, it might be that they have to accept TOS, not you.

FB has a huge amount of setting and from the info, you provide it's pretty hard to tell what exactly fails.

Comment: I have tried creating through Graph explorer, and getting the same error.. While I got the first time error, I accepted the terms from my account, and I was not the main admin user when I accepted it.

Now even if I open the terms page, from the main admin account, it says alre, aady accepted, and still not able to get the API working.

Please suggest, how to proceed.